# How can I run Burp Scanner so that a request two requests are sent one after the other in that order?

Tags: burp-suite

I have to scan 2 API requests and for the second API request to be successful, the first API request must be successful and vice versa. Each time Burp Scanner sends a request, it should go in this order:

- Request 1
- Request 2
- Request 1
- Request 2
- and so on.

How to order the requests?